# How to simplify $(3y)^{-2}×9y^2÷(3y^{-4})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Simplify $(3y)^{-2}×9y^2÷(3y^{-4})$

I know the answer is $y^4/3$ and I have a vague understanding of how to come up with this answer but I'm missing a few steps and continue to get the wrong answer. Thanks

---

I made an edit according to the original content of the OP. The one that he posted is as follows:

(3y)^-2 *9y^2/(3y^-4)

I know the answer is y^4/3 and i have a vague understanding of how to come up with this answer but i'm missing a few steps and continue to get the wrong answer. Thanks

Comment: @Parcly Taxel It should be $\frac{y^4}{3}$

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan kcan

Comment: Using these identities, you will be able to simplify your expression.

(i) $(a \cdot b)^n=a^n \cdot b^n$ 

(ii) $\frac{a^n}{b^m}=a^{n-m}$

(iii) $\frac{1}{a^n}=a^{-n}$

Comment: Makes way more sense now thanks guys

Comment: Well, to begin with get rid of the division sign  $a \div b = a \times \frac 1 b = a\times b^{-1} = \frac a b$.  Any of those will work. Also note $b^{-k} = \frac 1{b^k}$ and $\frac 1{b^{-k}} = b^k$.  The $\div$ sign is useful in arithmetic but useless, confusing, and utterly unnecessary in algebra.  Which is why grown-ups never use it.

Comment: Um, the answer (or question) is wrong.  $(3y)^{-2}\times 9y^2\div (3y)^{-4}=\frac{(3y)^{-2}\times 9y^2}{(3y)^{-4}}=(3y)^{-2}\times 9y^2\times (3y)^4 = \frac {9y^2\times (3y)^4}{(3y)^2} = 9y^2\times (3y)^2 = 9^2\times 9y^2 = 81y^4$.  I think maybe the question isn't puttig the parenthesis in the right place.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig Be careful of doing the edit. Because of the answer introduced by the OP, he really mean $3y^{-4}$ and not $(3y)^{-4}$

Comment: Oh, did the edit screw up the question.  Then .... I wasted a lot of time (or had it wasted).

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan  That was the way it was written when I edited the question.  I did wonder why it didn't match the given answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{(3y)^{-2}\cdot9y^2}{3y^{-4}}=\frac{3^{-2}y^{-2}\cdot 3^2y^2}{3y^{-4}}=\frac{1}{3y^{-4}}=\frac{1}{\frac{3}{y^4}}=\frac{y^4}{3}$$

Comment: by $(3y)^{-4} \ne 3y^{-4}$!!!!

Comment: @fleablood  Are you getting angry by putting too many exclamation marks? Look at the OP intention. He mentioned the answer as $\frac{y^4}{3}$. Did I introduced $(3y)^{-4}$?

Comment: Explamation points aren't anger.  Just ... exclaimation.  As in LOOK!  Okay, the OPs intention was $y^4/3$ but the *question* was $(3y)^{-4}$ which means either the OPs question or answer was wrong.  You did not introduce $(3y)^{-4}$ but the OP did.  You corrected it without any explanation of the correction.  $(3y)^{-2}\cdot9y^2\div(3y)^{-4}$ which is what the OP *wrote* is $\frac{(3y)^{-2}\cdot9y^2}{(3y)^{-4} }\ne \frac{(3y)^{-2}\cdot9y^2}{3y^{-4} }$ so you didn't answer the question the OP asked.  You answered the question *intended* but not the one asked.  Without explanation.

Comment: @ fleablood Okay, I stand corrected and sorry. But that was not the OP's intention. It was the one who made the edit.

Comment: Oh!... was the edit done after you answered?  I didn't see the original in that case.  I thought $(3y)^4$ was part of the original question.  My apologies if you thought I thought you were making an error.

Comment: @ fleablood Yes, you are correct.

Comment: No but you are correct also if the edit messed up the question.

Answer (score 0):

You mean;

$\frac{y^4.9.y^2}{3^2.3y^2}$

The resultant exponent of $y$ is $6-2=4$ by using laws of exponents.

And$(3)^{-2}= \frac 19=\frac {1}{(3)^2}$

And therefore, after dividing we get $\frac{y^4}{3}$

Comment: Utterly impossible to follow without mathjax.

Comment: How do we edit an answer...Plz help

Comment: What do you mean.  I don't like to edit other people's answers because I worry I might be reinterpretting what they meant.  (And I absolutely will *NEVER* correct what I think is a wrong answer.)  So I can't edit yours because I don't really know what you mean exactly.  To use mathjax put "\$" around the math.  To mak a fraction $\frac {numerator}{denominator}$ type "\$\frac {numerator}{denominator}\$"

Comment: I'll put the dollar signs in and put the fractions in.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had no idea about that

Answer (score 0):

I started to write a very long post about the many ways to do this in whatever order was comfortable, and then I realized the question is simply incorrect.

$(3y)^{-2}\times 9y^2\div (3y)^{-4}=\frac{(3y)^{-2}\times 9y^2}{(3y)^{-4}}=(3y)^{-2}\times 9y^2\times (3y)^4 = \frac {9y^2\times (3y)^4}{(3y)^2} = 9y^2\times (3y)^2 = 9y^2\times 9y^2 = 81y^4$

The question must have put a parenthesis in the wrong place.

At any event.  Bear in mind $(ax)^k = a^kx^k$ (and vice versa) and $x^kx^j= x^{k+j}$ and $a\div b= \frac ab = \frac ab^{-1}$ and $\frac {a^k}{a^j}= a^{k-j}$ and use those ideas in any order *you* feel comfortable with, you will get the answer eventually.

=====

I think the question was supposed to be $(3y)^{-2}2\times 9y^2\div (3y^{-4})$.

That gives the answer given.  (the parenthesis around the exponent; not the exponent outside the parenthesis.)

So $(3y)^{-2}\times 9y^2\div (3y^{-4})= \frac{(3y)^{-2}2\times 9y^2}{ 3y^{-4}}=$

$\frac {9y^2*y^4}{(3y)^2*3}=\frac{9y^6}{9y^2*3} = \frac {y^{6-2}}3 = \frac {y^4}3$

**OR** you can do it in any other order.  Whatever feels natural to you.